# How to hyperlink from pdf to add a event

Tags: pdf, hyperlink

I have created a hyperlink for my design in coreldraw. A Hyperlink to whatsapp, telegram, etc. Im making a event and i want to link the event to calendar. When a client click on the date it should add into the calendar of this mobile. Anyway or url or how it will be working. Any suggestion. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Go to [link](https://decomaan.github.io/google-calendar-link-generator/) fill all the details. Just hit generate and share the link.